# How to increase label padding on a colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy

I have a plot which is made with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10 , 11))
gs = GridSpec(nrows=12, ncols=10)
gs.update(wspace = 0, hspace = 0.5)

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:12, 0:10])
ax0.set_ylabel(r"$Pa\beta/H\alpha$")
ax0.set_xlabel(r"$H\alpha/H\beta$")
y0 = ax0.scatter(dcmergedf['HA_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HB_FLUX'], dcmergedf['PAB_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HA_FLUX'], s=300, c = dcmergedf['td_lmass'], cmap='coolwarm')
ax0.errorbar(dcmergedf['HA_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HB_FLUX'] ,  dcmergedf['PAB_FLUX']/dcmergedf['HA_FLUX']  , xerr = dcmergedf['BALMER_ERR'] , yerr = dcmergedf['PABHA_ERR'], c = 'black' , linestyle = 'None')
ax0.plot(dustcurvesdf['HAHB'] , dustcurvesdf['PABHA_CALZ00']*5 , c = 'blue' , label = '5 x Calzetti+00' , linestyle = '--')
ax0.plot(dustcurvesdf['HAHB'] , dustcurvesdf['PABHA_CALZ00'] , c = 'blue' , label = 'Calzetti+00')

ax0.plot(dustcurvesdf['HAHB'] , dustcurvesdf['PABHA_GORD03'] , c = 'green' , linestyle = ':' , label = 'Gordon+03')
ax0.plot(dustcurvesdf['HAHB'] , dustcurvesdf['PABHA_FITZ99'] , c = 'orange' , linestyle = '-.' , label = 'Fitzpatrick+99')

ax0.axis([1 , 10 , 0 , 1.8])
#ax0.legend(loc = 'upper left')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:1,1:9])
fig.colorbar(y0,ax3,use_gridspec=True,orientation='horizontal' ,  label = r'log$M_{\odot}$')
ax3.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
#ax3.xaxis.set_label_pad(0.1)
```

The resulting plot looks like
[image: plot with colorbar]

How do I increase the padding on the label of the colorbar so that it doesn't overlap with the colorbar itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the vertical alignement to `'bottom'` (default is `'basement'`):

```
ax3.xaxis.get_label().set_verticalalignment('bottom')
```

left: default (baseline), right bottom:

[image: baseline]   [image: bottom]